# Multiple same url htaccess redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I created a custom product/ecommerce website. It has a category, sub-category and product. Here are the urls that I want to redirect:

```
website.com/clothes
website.com/clothes/
website.com/clothes/tshirts
website.com/clothes/tshirts/
website.com/clothes/tshirts/bluepinned
website.com/clothes/tshirts/bluepinned/
```

Here are the .htaccess entries. Is there a way to write the following in one line? For example if the URL was, website.com/clothes/tshirts making sure the PHP files realise that I want to load the tshirts category, and not to display a product called tshirts in the clothes categor.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(clothes)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ products.php?c=$1&sc=$2&p=$3 [NC,L,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^(clothes)/([^/\.]+)/?$ products.php?c=$1&sc=$2 [NC,L,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^(clothes)/?$ products.php?c=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

I sometimes get 406 errors too when loading product images - are there any rewrite rules that could be making this happen. The actual images are in a separate directory anyway website.com/images/clothes/tshirts/bluepinned.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the conditions to each of the rules separately:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(clothes)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ products.php?c=$1&sc=$2&p=$3 [NC,L,QSA] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(clothes)/([^/\.]+)/?$ products.php?c=$1&sc=$2 [NC,L,QSA] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(clothes)/?$ products.php?c=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

It's also possible that there is a relative-vs-absolute path issue that could possibly be fixed by adding a

```
<base href="/">
```

in your page headers.

Comment: thanks - doesnt quite fix the 406 errors though. is there anything on the server that could cause images on the website.com/clothes/tshirts/bluepinned product to cause a 406? if i cache refresh it just spits out all these 406 errors for every resource, even though they exist

Comment: @Ourx it's unlikely that it is because of the rewrite rules. Maybe some other config somewhere. 406 usually means the browser (or whatever the client is) asked for a list of "acceptable" responses and the server decided the it couldn't fulfill any of them.

Comment: it couldnt fulfill them because there isnt enough memory or? so this really sounds like a server issue as opposed to a coding/developer issue? its not like i'm trying to execute an exe file or anything on the server, i just want to display an image :(